# Drilling up categoric to interval data?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, data-analysis, sufficient-statistics

This is a statical question.

I have a data set that provides the number of people readmitted to associated hospitals within 30 days of discharge (a common efficacy measure).  At immediate level of measurement I have categorical data:

Readmitted: Yes / No

I am confused about the implications for the unit of measure I am using: the number of of readmissions per zip code, over a one-year period of time.

Note that the unit of measure I am looking at I could 0 -> n readmissions (interval data).

Can the unit of measure be used to transform categoric data interval data?  Are there special precautions in this situation (I intend to run one of the following ANCOVA, logistic regression, or decision tree)?

Comment: Probably a better question for cross validated (stats.stackexchange.com).

Comment: If the choice is among nominal, ordinal, interval, and ratio, then ratio is the right choice because there is a non-arbitrary zero point. But I'd want to know more about your problem before saying anything about which method to use. In logistic regression you're typically trying to predict "yes" or "no" based on something either (e.g. how much time ellapsed after discharge?) This question might get better answers at stats (dot) stackexchange (dot) com. $\qquad$

Comment: The statistical testing looks at use of Electronic Health Records (IV) over Time (IV) and there effect on 30 Day Readmission (DV).  I wish to hold covariates such as Income and Age constant (CVs).  Logistic Regression and/or Decision Trees are back up analyses in case assumptions are not met for the ANCOVA.I am confident in my testing.  However, this is the first situation where the level of data has changed its type.  I also find that I can "talk" myself into certain aspects of statistics.